# Batch command 'for' is not working

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have the following line:

```
for %i in (bin\Setup) do if not %i == setup.exe del %i
```

This for pretends to delete all files in `bin\Setup` except from the one called **setup.exe**, but it's not working...

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use PowerShell: `get-childitem -file bin\Setup\* -exclude setup.exe | remove-item -whatif` (remove `-whatif` to actually delete)

Comment: I need to use regular command batch, because I don't want to install anything different.

Comment: PowerShell is built into the OS on Windows 7 and newer. There is nothing to install.

Comment: So, why it's not recognizing get-childitem?

Comment: You have to start PowerShell and run the command from a PowerShell window.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
for %i in ("bin\Setup\*") do if /i not "%~nxi"=="setup.exe" echo del "%~fi"
```

Changes made:

- wildcard included to enumerate all the files in the folder.
- `if` is now case insensitive (`/i`)
- file references are quoted to avoid problems with spaces
- only the name and extension of the file (`%~nxi`) is tested. You can execute `for /?` to retrieve a full list of modifiers available.
- removal of the file uses the full path (`%~fi`) to it

This is written to be executed from command line. Inside a batch file the percent signs need to be escaped, replacing `%` with `%%`

```dos
for %%i in ("bin\Setup\*") do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="setup.exe" echo del "%%~fi"
```

`del` commands are prefixed with a `echo` so files are not removed, the command is just echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. It says 'it doesn't expect  "%%~nxi"=="setup.exe" at this moment. ??

Comment: Use `if /i not` instead of `if not /i`.